# Advice about building a WPF form to modify userSettings

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, xaml, settings

I'm totally new to C#, and got an assignment building a WPF form to modify settings in an existing C# program using Visual Studio and WPF.

**I have numerous goals:**

1. Get a list of all of the Settings names.
2. Retrieve all of the user properties.
3. Add a line for every setting to the form, and allow the user to restore the original settings, use the current ones, or modify them to a new value.
4. Make sure that the user input is in the correct Type.
5. Bind between the TextBox and the values in the line, not sure what is the best way to send the details. What object do you recommend to bind to the xaml? The list containing the property lines? Or to bind every line separately?

I think that I need to access the App.config file for 3, so far unsuccessfully. I would have like to get an advice about the architecture, since I'm new to VS, C# and WPF.

Comment: The scope of this question is quite broad. Even though you're asking for "some advice" I think you could well find people consider this out of scope or unsuitable for SO. Good luck.

Comment: You'll just want to create your user interface, bind it to a class, then save them in the app.config. Use [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/managing-application-settings-dotnet?view=vs-2017) for reference on how to do that.

Comment: I would have to agree with everyone else here. This is not a suitable task for a beginner in WPF. There are too many other considerations besides WPF that you need to understand first. I would suggest running through a tutorial first. For example: https://wpf-tutorial.com/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an assignment suitable for someone new to wpf let alone c#.
Even experienced wpf developers are likely to find some tricky bits in this task.

app.config will be in the same folder as your exe. If that is in program files then you will not be able to edit and save. Unless your users are win 7 or earlier.

User settings will usually be stored in appdata for this reason. Since the user is expected to likely want to change them.
They go in a user.config file. The location of one off my system is:

C:\Users\Andrew\AppData\Local\MapEditor\MapEditor.exe_Url_aszfdqs5110y44xmg0kfuuqbatf5la5a\1.0.0.0\user.config

I am user Andrew on the machine and these are the user settings for MapEditor.exe.

The file itself is xml.

In there I see

And there's a bunch of stuff inside that.

I would not try and edit xml directly.
And this is your first bit you'll find isn't exactly easy.
Because you need to translate xml.
"All the user properties."
You presumably know what they are.
Because the user can't just add them.
They need to be defined in the app.

I'd pick out the pieces you want them to change and copy data to a viewmodel. Or observable collection of viewmodels presented by a parent viewmodel.
Probably simplest as an observablecollection.
You can then have a different viewmodel class per type of property.
They enter a string in a number then it'll fail to transfer back to the viewmodel and you can trap validation.errors that'll bubble.
To save, translate the viewmodels back into xml and save it.